# ajax gets empty responseText once piping intermediate data to python at backend

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, perl, backend

The background is, frontend passed an id back to backend and backend uses the id to extract information from database. The extracted data need further processing at backend and then gets sent back to frontend.

Here is the front end code:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="loadPage.js">

    </script>
</head>
<body onload = "loadPage()">
    <div id="stack"><p>test part</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
function __getParameters() {
    var parm = {};
    var url = window.location.href;
    var pairs = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        pair = pairs[i].split('=');
        parm[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    }

    return parm;
}

function __loadData(star) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           // var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
            if (xmlhttp.responseText == "") {
                document.getElementById("stack").innerHTML = "f*ck";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("stack").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    var url = "getXML.pl";
    url = url + "?STAR=" + star;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function loadPage() {
    var parm = __getParameters();
//    document.getElementById("stack").innerHTML = parm["STAR"];
    if (parm == undefined) {
        // wrong url error page
    } else if (parm['STAR'] == undefined) {
        // missing star error page
    } else if (parm['user' == undefined]) {
        // missing user id error page
    } else {
        var star = parm["STAR"];
        var user = parm["user"];
        __loadData(star);
    }

}
```

The backend uses perl to extract data from database, and it will print the output to stdout. The output is a XML in string form. Then I must use an existed python script to process the extracted data.

However, the server seems not support python (But the server can run python if I directly run python scripts on it. The reason for my statement is that I wrote a python cgi and I got a 500 error, while the perl cgi is ok. I'm sure the python script is correct since it can run directly on the server. I have no access to error log and I cannot modify the config file of the server).

So I piped the output of the perl script to python, and run it using 'system()'. The python script will output a processed string to stdout.

Here is the backend scripts:

perl script:

```
#!/depot/perl-5.14.2/bin/perl
# extract posted data
local ($buffer, @pairs, $pair, $name, $value, %FORM);
$ENV{"REQUEST__METHOD"} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
if ($ENV{"REQUEST_METHOD"} eq "POST") {
    read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{"CONTENT_LENGTH"});
} else {
    $buffer = $ENV{"QUERY_STRING"};
}

@pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
foreach $pair (@pairs) {
    ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $buffer);
    $value =~ tr/+/ /;
    $value =~ s/%(..)/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
    $FORM{$name}  = $value;
}
$star = $FORM{STAR};

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
my $cmd = "***/sq_star.pl --xml --star_id " . $star;
$cmd = $cmd . " | ***/python parseXML.py";
system($cmd);
```

the sq_star.pl (I just remove the path here and replace it with ***) near the end of perl script is just an existed script that will extract data from database. And parseXML.py is an existed script which does a lot to the input string.

The strange thing is, the responseText is always an empty string. I tried to run the perl script directly on the server, it can print expected results. And if I remove `$cmd = $cmd . " | ***/python parseXML.py";`, the responseText will be the data extracted from the database.

What I have tried for now:
1. I wrote a simple test python with just one line of print. Still empty response
2. I tried to store the output as `` $output =`$cmd`; `` and `print $output;` in the perl script, still empty.
3. I tried to store the original data in a txt and let the python read from the txt. Still empty

It seems that that data processed by python just cannot be sent back .....

-------------------update----------------
It seems to be the problem of the server. I guess the server is not set to support python so if I directly send requests to a python script on backend, there will be 500 error. But somehow my way, i.e., calling python in perl, gets around the error, but still the python just doesn't work... Just my guess

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, and actually if write as you suggested, bash will fault, telling me no such file. And I don't think this is the pipe problem, since instead of using pipe, I've already tried to write the output to temp.txt and let the python script read in from temp.txt, still empty response.

Comment: how about having the python script print the result to a text file, then slurp the results from the text file in using perl? at least you could then see if the python script is running and not dying somewhere.

Comment: I found the problem. It is because the interpreter I specified cannot be found by the server. system(...) line actually doesn't run at all. The reason that I didn' t see a ny error is because system() hides the error for me. Actually the return value of system() is -1, which means something wrong. I should have checked the return value. Any way, thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It is because the interpreter I specified cannot be found by the server. system(...) line actually doesn't run at all. The reason that I didn' t see any error is because system() hides the error for me. Actually the return value of system() is -1, which means something wrong. I should have checked the return value